# Where is the Stack Overflow flair page?

Tags: support, flair

I remember of opening Stack Overflow (or other related sites?), and realize that we can put our badges of Stack Overflow in our own blog.

Now, I found it hard to find it again. Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Two easy steps:

1. Click on your user name to open your [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427793/swdev).
2. Under your picture (gravatar), click on the link entitled ["**got flair?**"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair).

Comment: the link is not there...

Comment: @Warren: Okay, then use [the other direct link](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair). It still works fine.

Comment: I was just informed that flair got its own tab between "prefs" and "accounts". Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair